# Hide bar (at the bottom) of ios when connect ipad to bluetooth keyboard

Tags: ios, cordova, ipad

Hi I'm developing phonegap/cordova project for ios device -- ipad. The app receive input text via **bluetooth keyboard** (because I don't want to show the keyboard on the screen). So far app can receive input as expected But about the apperance How can I remove or hide the bar at the bottom of the screen? (please see images in the link below)

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/rt5w3ccqomec335/AADKUvt0w6KigfADAsx-ciu_a?dl=0

*Here are my code*

Config.xml:

```
<preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
```

HTML:

```
<div style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; width: 1px; height: 1px; left: -500px">
     <input id="input" type="textfield" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off">
</div>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('input').focus();
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Install this plugin to your project :https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-keyboard

And use this in JS : `cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);`
Documentation detail: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-keyboard#keyboardhidekeyboardaccessorybar